# Stop two or more click events from the same click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a button in jsp page and i have written two click functions for the same button, one with the tag and the other with the class/id of the button. Now, when i click on the button, both the click functions are getting called one by one. My requirement is that inside the first click function, i want to stop the second click function. I do not want to remove the remove the second click function as in some cases i need it to execute.

Below is the code i'm trying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input[type=button]").click(function(e){

if(true) {
alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
}
else {
// I want to remove the second click function here
}
});

$("#test").click(function(){
   alert("Test paragraph was clicked.");

  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = 'button' value='test' id='test'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the same event being _bubbled_ upwards, to stop it bubbling you'll need to `.stopPropagation`

Comment: It's not bubbling, the click occurs on the same element

Comment: @Huangism oh if it's the same element then you'd want to `.stopImmediatePropagation`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(evt){
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ....
});
```

This prevents "sideways bubbling", for want of a better phrase, i.e. further event callbacks bound to the same element from firing.

Comment: thanks. this one combined with return false did the trick..:)

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` is not jQuery specific. You can also use it when using native `addEventListener`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Answer (score 1):

You should try to put

```
return false;
```

in the **else** statement. Since it stops the propagation of the event it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed at most once per element.